# Overwrite extension file with theme version

Tags: theme, third-party-module, magento2.4.4

I'm using an extension from a vendor. The vendor is doing some magento frontend manipulation adding
some extra form fields to account create page. Now that module is in control/overwriting the magento version.

How can overwrite/control the vendor version from my theme?

Answer (score 0):

To add custom form fields to the account create page, they (3rd-party extension) need to add field content in phtml file, so you need to find this file and copy that file to your theme:

Eg: the module name of the vendor's extension is `Vendorname_Modulename` and the phtml file from the extension is:`vendor/vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/templates/customer/customfields.phtml`

Your overwrite file path should be: `app/design/yourvendorname/themename/Vendorname_Modulename/templates/customer/customfields.phtml`